# How to recover from an apt-get problem

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, octave

I was trying to install readline as a dependence for octave 4.0.0.

Then the problem with `apt-get install` and the hint to execute

```
sudo apt-get -f install.
```

The following is what I receive:

```
xxxx@xxxx-MS-7577:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for xxxx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
30 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1.205 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6.560 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 234980 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev-i386_2.21-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev-i386 (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.21-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/fpu_control.h', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64:i386 2.21-0ubuntu4
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.21-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I can recover from this?

```
$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=wily
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="15.10 (Wily Werewolf)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 15.10"
VERSION_ID="15.10"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"

~$ uname -a 
Linux xxxx-MS-7577 4.2.0-18-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:25:50 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Update:**

Thanks.
If I run this command I receive the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove libc6-amd64:i386 libc6-dev-amd64:i386
[sudo] password for xxxx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-5-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 lib32readline6-dev : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 but it is not going to be installed
 lib32tinfo-dev : Depends: lib32c-dev
 lib64readline6:i386 : Depends: libc6-amd64:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
 lib64readline6-dev:i386 : Depends: libc6-dev-amd64:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 lib64tinfo5:i386 : Depends: libc6-amd64:i386 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
 libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.21-0ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The problem now is I can't upgrade the system. I am locked in this error.
Trying to execute `sudo apt-get -f install` is useless because I enter in the previous error condition.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libc6-dev-i386 libc6-dev-amd64:i386`

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `libc6-dev-amd64:i386`

```
sudo apt-get remove libc6-amd64:i386 libc6-dev-amd64:i386
```

It is used only for 64bit (amd64) cross-compilation in 32bit (i386) Ubuntu installation .